# A notion of limit sketches that makes theories unique up to equivalence

Tags: ct.category-theory, sketches

There are multiple ways to formalize the notion of a (limit) sketch, which are basically equivalent. This makes it a bit difficult to decide on a "right way" to formalize sketches. One nice property would be that a category of models (in say $\mathsf{Set}$) is given by a unique theory up to equivalence.

My (probably flawed) understanding is that based on a particular weak definition of "sketch" this need to be the case and that a sketch may care about the way we axiomatize our theory, like e.g. whether we use a constant and a binary operation to say what a monoid is or a sequence of operators $(\prod : A^n \to A)$ or something else.

Let's only focus on limit sketches (since these yield the theories I actually care about).

> What is the correct notion of limit sketch where category of models are given by a unique theory up to equivalence?

Comment: Do you know the notion of a limit sketch in Adamek-Rosicky's book on locally presentable and accessible categories? It seems quite natural to me. But I don't know if this answers your question (which I don't fully understand, tbh).

Comment: @HeinrichD Consider some algebraic theory. There are multiple syntactical theories, i.e. pairs of the form (signature, equations) that are equivalent in the sense that they give you the same category of models in $\mathsf{Set}$. Now there should be some method for turning a syntactical theory into a limit sketch with the same models in $\mathsf{Set}$. I'm unsure whether the limit sketches for different but equivalent (same models) syntactical theories are actually equivalent as categories or not, e.g. using the definition by Adamek-Rosicky. That would be a desirable property to have.

Comment: Or to be more blunt: I want $\operatorname{Mod} \mathcal{T} \simeq \operatorname{Mod} \mathcal{T'} \Rightarrow \mathcal{T} \simeq \mathcal{T'}$ (if the category of models are the same then so are the sketches).

Comment: @StefanPerko that is a really strong requirement... never the less I would say that the answer is true if both $\mathcal T$ and $\mathcal T'$ have the same signature. Are you looking for something of more general?

Comment: @GiorgioMossa Yes, I do (if possible). I want the limit sketch to be oblivious to any *particular* signature (say groups via $1,\cdot, ^{-1}$ and $1, /$ should give me the same sketch).

Comment: @StefanPerko ok, give me sometimes. I've to refresh some stuff.

Comment: Well, for finite limit theories there's always Gabriel-Ulmer duality, which gives a contravariant equivalence between small finitely complete categories and locally finitely presentable categories. This would seem to be exactly what you want. (Regarding the comments under Giorgio's answer below, note that finitely complete categories are automatically idempotent complete.)

Comment: @ToddTrimble Perhaps I was a bit hasty accepting an answer already. Your comment pointed me further in the right direction. It also occurred to me that in the case of Lawvere theories the duality fails (as shown in Giorgio's answer) because they are not necessarily Cauchy complete.

Comment: This paper http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/10/20/10-20.pdf seems to include a generalization of Gabriel-Ulmer duality that allows for some more limits (infinitary products).

Comment: Yes, indeed; that's a good paper. And have you looked at Adamek and Rosicky's book? There are extensions of Gabriel-Ulmer duality there as well. I regard (limit) sketches as akin to signatures for algebraic theories: they are good for concise presentations, but in order to get a more invariant notion of theory, you have to "saturate" the class of (partial) operations; in the classical Gabriel-Ulmer case this is done by passing to the category of finitary right adjoints $\mathcal{M} \to \text{Set}$ where $\mathcal{M}$ is the given category of models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question you are looking for some definition of limit-sketches such that if two sketches $\mathcal T$ and $\mathcal T'$ are Morita-equivalent (that is the categories of their $\mathbf{Set}$-valued models are equivalent)  then they are equivalent as categories.

If that is the case they you are doomed to fail. The problem lies down to the fact that any reasonable definition of limit-sketch should comprise algebraic theories as a special case, meaning that any algebraic (i.e. Lawvere) theory should be a limit-sketch.

Unfortunately it is well know that there are non equivalent algebraic theories giving rise to the same categories of algebras (models).

As an example, taken from *Adàmek, Rosicky and Vitale's Algebraic theory*, you can consider the algebraic theories $\mathcal N$, the full sub-category of $\mathbf{Set}$ spanned by the finite sets $[n]=\{1,\dots,n\}$, and its full subcategory $\mathcal T_2$ spanned by sets of the form $[2n]$. In the above mentioned book is proven that the category of models $\text{Alg}(\mathcal N)$ and $\text{Alg}(\mathcal T_2)$ are both equivalent to $\mathbf{Set}$ but that two theories are not equivalent as categories.

Comment: Ah... I was completely unaware of this. One thing though: The book (that I actually had already...) mentions that two Lawvere theories are Morita equivalent iff they have equivalent idempotent completions. Do you know whether the idempotent completion of a limit sketch can be used as a theory in place of the limit sketch itself somehow?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not aware of that. On the other hand I am not even sure if a similar result extend to limit-sketches.